# ViewHolder tag issue with AsyncTask in loading Thumbnail

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, thumbnails, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to write my own custom `CursorAdapter` that will show a text and an image next to it. I'm using view holder pattern and `AsyncTask`for the loading of the images. The code I wrote works fine and loads evrything nice until I start scrolling the list down than the images that are loaded into the thumbnail are duplicates of those that appeared in the rows above that were already scrolled up.I tried lots of tutorials couldn't find what I'm doing wrong here. Help will be very appreciated.

```
public class MyCustomCurserAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView nameText;
        public ImageView imageThumbnail;
        public int position;
    }

    public MyCustomCurserAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        int pathCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(NewPicSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PATH);
        String imageInSD = cursor.getString(pathCol);  
        File imgFile = new  File(imageInSD);

        if(imgFile.exists()){

            int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(NewPicSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PIC_NAME);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameCol);

            if (name != null) 
                holder.nameText.setText(name);

            ImageTask task = new ImageTask(holder,cursor.getPosition());
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor cur, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_pic_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder;

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic_name_entry);
        holder.imageThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic_thumbnail);
        holder.imageThumbnail.setTag(Integer.valueOf(cur.getString(NewPicSQLiteHelper.INDEX_COLUMN_ID)));
        holder.position = cur.getPosition();
        // The tag can be any Object, this just happens to be the ViewHolder
        view.setTag(holder);
        return view;

    }



    private class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
        private final WeakReference <ImageView> imageViewReference;

        int viewID;
        ViewHolder taskHolder;

        public ImageTask(ViewHolder holder,int position) {
            taskHolder = holder;
            ImageView imageView = taskHolder.imageThumbnail;
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference <ImageView> (imageView);
            viewID = position;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String path = params[0];
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path,75,75);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    Log.d("AsyncTask", "ImageView null");
                    if (result != null) {
                        if(viewID == taskHolder.position){
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                            imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                            Log.d("AsyncTask", "Image position right");
                        }
                    } else {

                        Log.d("AsyncTask", "Image positions wrong");
                        imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String orgImagePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

            ////.........
        }



        private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            ////.........

}
```

Comment: Did you fix the issue you were having? I think you need to override the `getView()` method as well to get the contents of the holder from the view tag when the view is about to be displayed.